# Suppose $f \circ g$ is one-to-one and $f$ is not one-to-one. Show that $g$ is not onto.

Tags: functions, proof-writing

Given $A,B,C$ are sets and $g$ and $f$ are functions such that $g: A\rightarrow B, f: B\rightarrow C$.

Intuitively, I can ambiguously argue why this is true with a couple of sketches, but I'm having trouble proving this formally.

My proof goes as follows: (by contradiction)

> Suppose $f \circ g$ is injective, $f$ is not injective and $g$ **is** surjective. I want to show this is impossible.
>
> Let's assume we found $a,a'\in A$ such that $(f\circ g)(a) = (f\circ g)(a')
> \iff f\big(g(a)\big) = f\big(g(a')\big)$
>
> Well, we know $g$ is surjective, that means for all $b\in B$, there exists $a \in A$ such that $g(a) = b$, thus we can conclude that both $g(a),g(a')$ are in B.
>
> So we know there exists $b, b'\in B$ such that $b = g(a)$ and $b' = g(b') \iff f(b) = f(b')$

Now this is where I feel like I can create the contradiction by saying there exists $b$ and $b'$ such that $f(b) = \big(f(b')\big)\implies b \not= b'.$ (Given $f$ is not $f$ is not injective).

But how do I do this? I can show that $b \not= b'$, but how can I use that to show that there exists $a, a' \in A$ such that $(f \circ g)(a) = (f\circ g)(a') \implies a \not= a'$, thus raising that contradiction?

Thanks,

Comment: The line "Let's assume we found some a,a' in A such that (f o g)(a) = (f o g)(a')" doesn't make much sense.  You just assumed that $f\circ g$ is injective, so we know $a=a'$.

Comment: Yes, but I also want to show it cannot be the case in general. See, that's what I'm trying to lead to, I have explicitly put that up to bring that 'that does not make sense moment', a.k.a contradiction.

Comment: You have just assumed that it cannot be the case, in the previous sentence.  It would be very easy to prove things if you were just allowed to assume they are true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your starting assumption

> Let's assume we found some a,a' in A such that (f o g)(a) = (f o g)(a')

is problematic. What contradiction could possibly arise from that?

Instead, get the contradiction from the assumptions of the hypothesis together with the assumption that $g$ is surjective.

Here's one way . . .

Assume $g:A\to B$, and $f:B\to C$ are such that

- $f{\,\circ\,}g$ is injective.

  $f$ is not injective.

  $g$ is surjective.

Our goal is to derive a contradiction.

Since $f$ is not injective, there exist $b,b' \in B$, with $b\ne b'$ such that $f(b)=f(b')$.

Since $g$ is surjective, there exist $a,a'\in A$, such that $g(a)=b$, and $g(a')=b'$,

Since $b\ne b'$, we have $g(a)\ne g(a')$, hence, since $g$ is a function, it follows that $a\ne a'$.

But then
$$(f{\,\circ\,}g)(a) = f(g(a)) = f(b) = f(b') = f(g(a'))=(f{\,\circ\,}g)(a')$$
so we have $a\ne a'$, and $(f{\,\circ\,}g)(a) = (f\circ g)(a')$, contrary to assumption that $f{\,\circ\,}g$ is injective.

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is nor one-to-one, then there exists $a\ne b, f(a)=f(b).$  If we assume by way of contradiction that $g$ is surjective, then there are $c,d$ such that $g(c)=a, g(d)=b.$

Take it from here.